# What to do with the question which just asked to attract votes and to gain reputation

Tags: discussion, questions, help-improvement

I have been encountered some question where new users posted the question at very high level (even in Meta).

When I checked some of these users profile, I realize these users have not participates enough in any other activity which help Stackoverflow users, apart from asking very high level question, where answer is already present in FAQs. To me these type of questions look like an attempt to gain upvotes and build reputation.

Can we use flag --> "in need of moderator intervention" to bring this to Moderator notice? or my observation is not correct here?

Please pardon me if I sound like critic, but I feel this has to bring into notice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of gardening is very common:(

Comment: No, don't use flags.

Comment: As far as I can tell that user has 25 answers and 1 question on main so I'm not sure what triggered you to pick that as an example. Also, noone gains any rep on meta.

Comment: My bad. I just check meta profile for this user... but i have seen many other users doing the same... even the above example not looks correct because guidelines are already define on how to filter the invalid questions... then i don't understand the reason for asking the question other then gaining reputation.

Comment: Say that the answer is "yes", you do flag for moderator attention. Can you detail what you would then do? What would you put as an explanation in the flag? I'll give you a hint: the idea is that you tell the moderators what needs to be done, you don't flag for attention and then they have to discover that for themselves.

Comment: Maybe they earned their rep like you did, by posting more answers than questions....

Comment: Hi Pool Party Renekton.... I only ask question when i face any trouble during programming... and answer only when i think i know the answer... I am not sure why you commented like this

Comment: Like how? I'm not condemning how you earn your rep, I'm just giving those users the benefit of the doubt. @TotaloDotoNeto

Comment: The goal of Stack Exchange, as I currently understand it, is to create a useful database of questions and answers.  Only factual, objective responses related directly to questions belong here.  Statements about *those posting* are inappropriate.

Comment: At least if the questions are high level, and receive high level answers, other developers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all:

### No.

Don't flag it for moderator attention.
If the question is bad: downvote, comment or close-vote. Only get the mods involved for issues that can't be solved by normal users. Questions that get answered in SO's help pages usually get closed quick enough.

That said, any user (that isn't suspended) can ask questions on SO / Meta. Just because they're not that experienced on the site, doesn't mean they're not allowed to ask certain questions.

Answer (score 9):

**No**. Don't bring the mods into this unless there is something really wrong.

Next, You are focusing too much on they **type of users**. As a thumbrule always remember- *always talk about posts and never about people who posted them*. This directly supports - *vote based on quality of posts rather than the reputation of person who posted them*.

> To me these type of questions look like an attempt to gain upvotes and
>   build reputation.

Well, making that assumption is actually wrong. As the other answer suggests - If the post is bad, down-vote it , close it, and delete it (if it is really bad) irrespective of *who posted it*